# Как я могу оптимизировать код?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу оптимизировать такой код?
Знаю, что как-то можно не писать кучу классов и id, а использовать переменную this.
Однако, когда я попробовал через нее сделать, то у меня по нажатию на любое место срабатывает функция или просто тот элемент, по которому нажимал, закрывался.
Ccылка на кодпен
https://codepen.io/Misha_mishy/pen/abzRwrO?editors=1111

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( ".slideToggle-2" ).click(function(){        
      $(".toggle__content-2").slideToggle(); 
    });

    $( ".slideToggle-3" ).click(function(){        
      $(".toggle__content-3").slideToggle(); 
    });

    $( ".slideToggle-3" ).click(function(){
      $(".toggle__content-3").slideToggle(); 
    });

    $( ".slideToggle-4" ).click(function(){        
      $(".toggle__content-4").slideToggle(); 
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('[class^=slideToggle]').on('click',function(){
    $(this).prev('[class^=toggle__content]').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.toggle__content-2,
.toggle__content-3,
.toggle__content-4{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="toggle__content-2"> какой-то текст</p>
 <div class="slideToggle-2">Показать текст </div>

<p class="toggle__content-3"> какой-то текст</p>
 <div class="slideToggle-3">Показать текст </div>

<p class="toggle__content-4"> какой-то текст</p>
 <div class="slideToggle-4">Показать текст </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!